# Is there any other way to pass complex object with Intents?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

So I've got quite complex datatypes that needs to be sent through an Intent.
All these types comes as part of a base-class (BaseResponse), that have alot of child-classes, these child-classes also includes loads of different complex-datatypes.
I would love if there was a way so I only had to implement the Parcelable on for example the child-classes, but it seems all members of classes implementing Parcelable needs to be Parcelable as well?

If the answer is something other than "No, stop being lazy" you win some of my Internets for today.

PS. These types are all auto-generated from a WSDL so I sort of wish I didn't have to edit them all manually.
DS.

Quick edit: I know of the Serializable interface but it would pose the same problem.

2nd edit: I noticed you could pass Arrays of Objects through the Intent, Im not sure if this is going to serialize it as an Object (aka with no members) or if I can just type-cast it back when I receive the Array.
Ill try it out and report back

3rd edit: The whole putting Object-arrays in the Intent wont work I guess and being lazy I'm going with the JSON-serializing option and marking it as answer (even though I havent tried it but guess it should work if a stranger on the Internet says so)

Final edit: I am now using the Json-serializing way marked as correct answer and it works just fine. There are some limitations to what objects Gson can serialize but nothing that concern me. There is probably a very in-efficient way (in terms of cpu) of doing this but the time it saved me from having to implement the interface explicitly for ~300 classes is worth it.
Thank you all for the rapid answers and suggestions, StackOverFlow is without a doubt the best community on all of history of mankind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used GSON library to first convert my object into string(JSON string) and then put into intent extra.

And at the time of receiving it convert it back to original object.

Works fine for me but don't know if it is an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, actually quite helpfull, thing is I noticed you could use writeArray(), and most of the complex objects in the BaseResponse-child classes comes in Arrays so I might actually get around of implementing the interface on all of my data-types.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct as the question did actually ask for an ALTERNATIVE way of passing the complex objects through Intents. All you guys who said "Implement the interface, do it correct", sorry never was much for following rules

Answer (score 1):

There's no other alternative I think, Else you can use Database to fill that data (if possible), and then pass its key (Table's primary key) or something to achieve it. Don't kill me if you have considered it also already! :O

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `Parcelable` for **all** classes (not sure why it is a surprise to you :) is the right way of doing this on Android.

Comment: Yeah go figures, but to quote Gates "Always have a lazy developer do complex tasks because if there's and easy way to do it he will find it".

Comment: Implementing Parcelable is trivial, clean and THE way of doing this on Android. Not sure why you want to waste time on "workaround". Maybe, assuming you like quotes, because "it was hard to write so it should be hard to read" policy. Still, it's not professional approach.

Comment: Trivial doesnt mean its not time-consuming. Ive got ~300 classes that I would have to implement this interface for. I tried the way with Json-serializing and it worked just fine with this approach I wrote 5 lines of codes for all classes compared to lets say the ~1000 lines implementing the interface would have taken.